# Tell if stdout is a tty using MPI in C

Tags: c, mpi, stdout, tty, mpiexec

During the execution of a C compiled program in a terminal, `isatty(fileno(stderr))` as well as `isatty(0)` returns 0 in my code when I use the `mpirun` or `mpiexec` commands.

Why ? and How do I know if stdout is a terminal or redirected while using MPI ?

I'm actually printing colored stuff, but this makes the output parsing harder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MPI processes are started through an ssh tunnel. So std out goes through the tunnel. I have no idea what `isatty` says about that.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Hi, and thanks for your reply. I can't find anything related to MPI processes using ssh tunnels, except when using MPI over multiple computers over ssh. Could you provide more information about what you are talking about ?

Comment: See the accepted answer. That says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mpirun/mpiexec starts all processes with stdout/stderr connected to a pipe or socket that leads back to the mpirun process.  The mpirun process collects everything from all of these pipes/sockets and copies it to its stdout.

So only mpirun itself still has stdout/stderr still connected to a terminal.  Any other process will see its stdout/stderr connected to a non-terminal.

Your best bet is to use an argument or environment variable to control whether the output is colored or not.